# How to use case in 'where' in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error,

> Expression invalid in condition inside case.

while running MySQL:

```
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN TBL1.Reissued<>'1'
            THEN
                fare IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                fare <> 0.00
    END

WHERE
    fare IS NOT NULL
    AND 
    fare <> 0.00
```

Comment: Are you using T-SQL from Microsoft or MySQL - they are different.

Comment: For some reason, people learn about `CASE` in SQL and want to use it in all kinds of ways when simple boolean logic (AND, OR, NOT) can be used to combine the conditions far more easily. Not sure why this specifically happens in SQL.

Comment: Probably you should Google how to use `CASE` in SQL.  I don't even understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First, `fare IS NOT NULL AND fare <> 0.00` can be simplified to `fare <> 0.00`, because any condition will eliminate `NULL`, as every comparison to `NULL` value evaluates to `unknown` which can be thought of as false.

Now, you can use such condition:

```
where (TBL1.Reissued<>'1' and fare <> 0.00) or TBL1.Reissued='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL `case` function, I think it returns a value or a table column only. Please refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) for your information.

From my point of view, it looks like you want to manipulate an SQL statement in the process of joining two tables on some condition. You can use `left join` to join it and use `case` to control the selected field.